# How to remove WordPress Default Comment? not Facebook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, comments, disqus

I want to remove the Wordpress default comments system from my website but Wanted to keep Facebook Comments Only. Just like Scoopwhoop.com is doing!

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Wordpress Development. This site is not a free coding service. Please show some effort and then try ro ask an exact fact-based question about yout problem. Questions like **I want to do something, how should I do that** or **Please do it for me** are considered off-topic and thus closed here.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much for helping me with my solution. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: BTW, I have already resolved my problem. Thank you!!!